# Auto Delete All Outlook Calendar Items in Deleted Folder

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

I am writing a simply script to delete all calendar objects within the Deleted Items folder. such calendar objects include meeting confirmations, declines...etc.

At present I have below, does not delete anything, even though checking the deleted items folder has many calendar confirmations, declines..etc:

```
    Dim oDeletedItems As Outlook.Folder
    Dim obj As Outlook.MailItem

    Dim i As Integer

    'Obtain a reference to deleted items folder
    Set oDeletedItems = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)
    For i = oDeletedItems.Items.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
    ' Delete all appointment items
     If oDeletedItems.Items(i).Class = AppointmentItem Then

         'Debug.Print obj.Subject
          oDeletedItems.Items.Item(i).Delete

     End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, do not use multiple dot notation `(oDeletedItems.Items(i).Class)` - cache the Items collection before entering the loop.

Secondly, confirmations, declines, etc. are meeting items, not appointments.

Thirdly, Class property returns one of the `OlObjectClass` enum values. `AppointmentItem` is an item type (interface).

You need to use 53 `(olMeetingRequest)` or 26 `(olAppointment)`.

Fourthly, start the loop from `Items.Count`, not `Items.Count-1`.

```
set items = oDeletedItems.Items
For i = items.Count To 1 Step -1
    ' Delete all appointment items
     set item = items.Item(I) 
     itemClass = item.Class
     If (itemClass= olAppointment) or (itemClass= olMeetingRequest) Then
          'Debug.Print obj.Subject
          item.Delete
     End If
    Next
```